# Arch - "ip a" only shows "lo"

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I have set up an Arch Linux system which had XFCE4 as a DE installed. While setting it up the way I like, I needed to reboot the machine. After that, my network interface was not found, I could not start Xorg ("Screens not found", but that's another problem...) and lightdm was broken (also another problem)

If I type "ip a" now, I only get the entry of "lo", while the interface which I used before was named "enp58s0f1".

I used both a repeater (which is connected to the router) and the ethernet connection directly, but both of them result in the same output...

I am pretty sure that it can't really be a driver/hardware error, for it already worked for a long time and i have several other distributions installed on the same machine on which there aren't any connection problems.

The problem already occured to other people, but none of the hints and solutions there worked for me.

[image: Photo of some relevant commands and their output]

Thanks for potential help,
Alexander Schoch

EDIT:

The following are photos of `lspci -vv`. I am really sorry to have made photos, but i cannot save the output to a file and i am not using a virtualbox...

[Photos of lspci -vv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSnNm.jpg)

EDIT2:

`pacman -Q linux && uname -r` results in `linux 4.15.1-2` and `4.14.15-1-ARCH`, respecitvely. I see that there is a mismatch...

EDIT3:

`mkinitcpio -k 4.15.1-2-ARCH` resulted in a positive result: It started a "dry run" (whatever that means)

Comment: What does `ip link` show?

Comment: @TorinCarey exactly the same as ip a, only "lo" with some information behind it

Comment: What about `lspci -nn`?

Comment: Are you in single-user mode?

Comment: @TorinCarey 

"3a:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)" 

"3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)"

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no. logged in as normal user "alexander_schoch" and entered sudo su

Comment: @AlexanderSchoch: edit your original post with the output of `lspci -vv` (you put just lspci  without -vv) with the relevant part

Comment: @GillesQuenot done. sorry for those terrible photos.

Comment: @AlexanderSchoch you don't have any module loaded for your ethernet card. Try to find which one is missing and load it with `modprobe module`

Comment: @GillesQuenot using `lspci -v`, i do not get the "Kernel module" output which was expected by archlinux.org - Network Configuration. How do you find out the module to load?

Comment: It's not `-v` but `-vv`, the command should tell us

Comment: @GillesQuenot I do not get anything either using the -vv option

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `pacman -Q linux && uname -r`

Comment: Yes, missmatch, maybe you can reboot and you will have the choice of the right kernel, or if not, then your `mkinitcpio` conf if wrong I guess

Comment: @GillesQuenot No, i cannot choose the Kernel. But the output of just `mkinitcpio` is `ERROR: /lib/modules/4.14.15-1-ARCH' is not a valid kernel module directory`. How can i adapt it to the correct dir?

Comment: You have to rebuild the initrd from a chroot.

Comment: Yes, take a live-cd of arch, then chroot and run proper mkinitcpio. Or the simplest way is to pacman -Sy linux, but your mkinitcpio.conf should be OK

Comment: @GillesQuenot and jasonwryan Thank you guys so much! I have just reinstalled the kernel and it works fine now. You even solved my Xorg problems.

Answer (score 2):

After examinating your `lspci -vv` output, I see that the module section is missing.

After some search on the web ,I discover wich module you miss, so try this :

```
modprobe r8169
```

if there's an error, please tell us

### Edit:

To understand what's going on under the hood :

```
# strace -f -e trace=file modprobe r8169
```

Check if there's some wrong paths.

### Edit2:

Update your system and reinstall your kernel in a chroot with :

```
pacman -Syu
```

(current linux kernel is 4.15, not 4.14)

Comment: okay. i tried that one and got "modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.15-1-ARCH".

I also tried the module rtsx_pci (the only one mentioned in "lspci -v") which resulted in the same output

Comment: The latest kernel is 4.15 in arch. I have it there : `/usr/lib/modules/4.15.1-2-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169.ko.xz`

Comment: What is the output of `find /usr/lib -name '*r8169*'` ?

Comment: in this directory, I got `8139cp.ko.xz`, `8139too.ko.xz`, `atp.ko.xz`and `r8169.ko.xz`. Using `modprobe thoseNames`, I get "Module theName not found in theDir"

Comment: Are you on a live-cd ?

Comment: No. I have arch installed on one of my hard disks.

Comment: and `find /usr/lib -name '*r8169'` did not give me any results (even though i have the files in the said directory)

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r` ?

Comment: `uname -r` results in "4.14.15-1-ARCH"

Comment: Check my edit...

Comment: I get "strace: command not found". Apparently, i do not have the missing package installed.

Comment: `-Syu linux`: [partial updates are not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported) (and likely what got OP into this mess in the first place).

Comment: Good catch @jasonwryan

Answer (score 1):

For all those who have the same problem:

Boot into an external system (like an arch linux live stick), chroot into the arch partition and re-download the linux package via pacman (remember to establish your internet connection before using the chroot command). This did the trick for me.

Best, 
Alexander Schoch

Comment: ??? What's the point ? That's exactly whats we said...

Comment: I know. But noone reads comments in stackexchange. That way, your solution is read at first sight.